# Linq to SQL Class (Stored procedure) in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, stored-procedures

I am using Linq to SQL Class in my project....For that I am drag and drop Stored procedure from Database to .dbml file that does not give me any error.
But while I am trying to get the returned column lists from stored procedure into IList<> select query in Linq ....It will not give column name to bind it with object...

As well as when I have looked over partial Linq class there is no property generated for that columns name....

So I think there is a problem with stored procedure.
(Stored procedure returns result in SQL Server)

Please suggest what I have to do change in Stored procedure....?

Comment: Have you set the return type on the stored procedure, in the designer on the right select the stored proc and go to the properties.

Comment: Yes I already tried with this also..

Answer (score 0):

I have appended properties manually for Partial class instead of auto generate by itself when drag and drop stored procedure into DBML...
It is working fine now...